# DataTable - ContextMenu

Tags: primefaces, contextmenu

Primefaces Migration-Guide 5.3 to 6.0:

> ContextMenu: p:contextMenu must be placed AFTER the target component (e.g. datatable) in the xhtml now.

I tried exactly that, but it' not working. No Menu at all.

Placing `ContextMenu` before `dataTable`: Menu is showing. Additional output on browser console:

> ContextMenu targets a widget which is not available yet. Please place the contextMenu after the target component. targetWidgetVar: widget_base_cars

My Webshpere Liberty log:

```
...org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener  I Running on PrimeFaces 7.0
```

Java:

```
java.version = 1.8.0_102
```

Stripped down to [primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml)

```html
<h:body>

    <h1>Context Menu</h1>
    <h2>ContextMenu: p:contextMenu must be placed AFTER the target component</h2>

    <h:form id="base" >

        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{dtContextMenuView.cars}" rowKey="#{car.id}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                List with #{dtContextMenuView.numberOfCars} Items
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Year">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Brand">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Color">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:contextMenu for="cars" >
            <p:menuitem value="Hello" />
            <p:menuitem value="World" />
        </p:contextMenu>


        <h2>but it fails</h2>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

I expect the menu to show on right click.

Is it a bug, or am i the bug?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this testing around with PF 5.3/6.0/7.0. I'm with you as long as your `p:dataTable` is not selectable:

The `p:contextMenu` appears on rightclick when added **above** the `p:dataTable` element in xhtml. When added **below**, no context menu appears at all. But tbh.: is a context menu useful on a datatable which does not allow selection?

When making it selectable by adding the attributes

```
selection="#{myBean.selectedValue}" selectionMode="singel"
```

it behaves like this:

- `p:contextMenu` below `p:dataTable` as suggested by migration guide: On rightclick, the clicked row is selected and context menu appears on it.
- `p:contextMenu` above `p:dataTable`: on rightclick, context menu appears either, but the row is not selected.

So if `p:contextMenu` is added above the table, selection does not work as expected which must be the reason for the migration guide telling "add it below!".

Btw: I did not get that warning in my JavaScript console during my tests, don't know why.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! My problem with the contextMenu exists in a more complex environment, so i stripped it down. Maybe too much. I have to check this out. Btw: I was running the example in development mode. Perhaps this is the reason for my JS-console warning